# Libboost dependencies on Ubuntu 14.04 during HHVM install

Tags: ubuntu, hhvm, ubuntu-14.04

I'm installing HHVM following these steps on a Ubuntu 14.04 machine.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-hhvm-hiphop-virtual-machine-on-an-ubuntu-13-10-vps

The result I'm getting is:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 hhvm : Depends: libboost-filesystem1.53.0 but it is not installable
        Depends: libboost-program-options1.53.0 but it is not installable
        Depends: libboost-system1.53.0 but it is not installable
        Depends: libboost-system1.53.0 but it is not installable
        Depends: libboost-regex1.53.0 but it is not installable
        Depends: libicu48 but it is not installable
        Depends: libtasn1-3 but it is not installable
        Depends: libboost-thread1.53.0 but it is not installable
```

Output of: `dpkg -s libboost-dev | grep 'Version'` = `Version: 1.54.0.1ubuntu1`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try this tutorial instead? https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Prebuilt-packages-on-Ubuntu-14.04

Comment: Same with these instructions http://fideloper.com/hhvm-nginx-laravel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those instructions are for Ubuntu 13.10. 14.04 has different requirements, so you should be following the instructions for [Prebuilt 14.04 packages](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Prebuilt-packages-on-Ubuntu-14.04) instead.

Comment: Damn, I assumed that it had to do with a fixed libboost or something... thanks :-)